# Consequences of transferring Android app between accounts

Tags: android

I need to transfer an Android app between accounts. I know that user reviews, downloads and other statics will be trasferred as well.

My question is to those who have done this process before. Does transferring an app affects your apps position in recommendations and/or rankings. I.e. will it affect organic traffic coming from Google Play in any way?